# How would I assign a control an order number?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a method which draws all the controls to the panel, but its draws them based on the order which I have listed them, which means PictureBox1 will always be *behind* all the other pictureboxes. Example:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox1.BackgroundImage,
    new Rectangle(PictureBox1.Location, PictureBox1.Size));

e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox2.BackgroundImage,
    new Rectangle(PictureBox2.Location, PictureBox2.Size));
```

it draws PictureBox1 **first**, then PictureBox2 **second**, then PictureBox3 **third** etc...

This means that PictureBox2 get drawn Over PictureBox1, and PictureBox3 gets Drawn over PictureBox2. Here's a pic to display overlapping images: [image]

Now when I push a button when focus is on picturebox2 I would like the DrawImage order to be changed so that PictureBox2 is drawn last.
I'm sure one of you has a great solution to this, I would like to listen to any suggestions you may have.

Comment: My first thought would be to have the PictureBoxes as a list, to draw you would use a foreach loop. You can then organise the draw order by sorting the list. EDIT: Sorry you didn't specify what you were using I am thinking about this in an XNA type way.

Comment: You would get better answers by providing a screenshot illustration of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right lol. I did a terrible job at explaining the situation. I'm gunna have another go at editing my original post and add more detail

Comment: just realized that I can't post images since I'm relatively new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you haven't made it clear what determines the order for all the other picture boxes in the panel. However, you can achieve the same effect using [SetChildIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx). To Swap the position of PictureBox1 with PictureBox2 for instance, you can do:

```
var p1ndex = panel.Controls.IndexOf(pBox1);
var p2ndex = panel.Controls.IndexOf(pBox2);
panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(pBox1, p1ndex);
panel.Controls.SetChildIndex(pBox2, p2ndex);
```

Here, `pBox1` could be the last PictureBox you hovered on and `pBox2` the current one you're hovering on...

Comment: Thanks Chibueze Opata. According to 2 posts it looks like using SetChildIndex is the best for this.

Comment: You're welcome, I also suggest you should change the Title of your question to "How do I change the Order of picture boxes on a panel". That way other people who have similar problems can see the question...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is WinForms, you can call

```
picturebox2.BringToFront()
```

before redrawing it.

If you need finer control than just "make me on top of all other controls" you can use [GetChildIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fz293fh.aspx) and [SetChildIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx).

Comment: Eric the .BringToFront() would not work when it is being drawn to a Panel. Before it is being drawn to the panel, the control disspears Then it is Drawn/Painted to the panel, & it is drawn in the order which I specified in the panel_paint event.

Comment: Oh, so the code you show is in the Panel's OnPaint?  Why not create a `SortedList<PictureBox>` holding your picture boxes and sorted on GetChildIndex. Use GetChildIndex/SetChildIndex to track the relative index you desire.  In your code, loop through the SortedList calling DrawImage on the PictureBox objects in the sorted order?

Comment: Yes that sounds about right Eric. I'll need to brush up on using SortedLists since I don't believe I've ever used one before lol so this would make a great starting point to learning it. Thanks Eric